# No data insertion (message: insertion successful)

Tags: c#

```
        private void iSave_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection.con))
        {                
            conn.Open();               
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [City] (name) VALUES (@Name)", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", city.Text.ToLower());                        
                    MessageBox.Show(city.Text);
                    MessageBox.Show("Insertion successful");
                }

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [State] (name) VALUES (@Name)", conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", state.Text.ToLower());
                    MessageBox.Show("Insertion successful");
                }
            conn.Close();
         }
    }
```

Program is not inserting, rows in the database tables are empty and I'm getting messages that insertion is successful. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried refreshing your dbms to check the table updates ?

Comment: You're not executing the command.

Comment: you are not executing the script in this way..

Comment: Well the message does not mean that much, since it will be shown regardless of the success of the operation. As long as there isn't any error in you c#-code, of course ... But for me it looks like you simply do not execute the SQL-Statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fail to execute the query - take a look at

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

i.e. you're missing

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

call.

```
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", city.Text.ToLower()); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                       
...
```

Comment: thanks, sorry I've missed that last time when I was copying/pasting/cutting :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to 
`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` your query.

Embed it along these lines:

```
 try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
    catch(SqlException e)
    {
        MessgeBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), "Error Message");
    }
```